# c++17 efficiently multiply parameter pack arguments with std::array elements

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to efficiently multiply the arguments from a parameter pack with the elements of a std::array:

```
int index(auto... Is, std::array<int,sizeof...(Is)> strides)
{
  // pseudo-code
  // int idx = 0;
  // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(Is); ++i)
  //   idx += Is[i] * strides[i];
  // return idx; 
}
```

I can't quite wrap my brain around this one. I started down the road of an index sequence, but I could figure out how to incorporate the summation.

I am using c++17, so fold expressions are fair game if they would simplify the code.

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT: Clarified the pseudo-code. The only pseudo part is the expression `Is[i]` which refers to the i'th parameter pack argument.

T.C.'s answer below was perfect and here is my final code which is a member function:

```
unsigned int index(auto... indexes)
{
    unsigned int idx = 0, i = 0;
    (..., (idx += indexes * m_strides[i++]));
    return idx;
}
```

As of this writing, the code compiles using gcc 6.3.0 with the -fconcepts flag, which brings in the Concept TS.

Using `auto... indexes` is shorthand for `template<typename Args> f(Args... indexes)`. I tried to use an unsigned int concept for the arguments, but I couldn't get that to work.

The (...,) fold is the key element and expands to something like (if you could actually [] into the parameter pack):

```
idx += indexes[0] * m_strides[i++], idx += indexes[1] * m_strides[i++], etc.
```

That was the insight I was missing.

Comment: I'm curious what compiler you are using.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod gcc 6.3.0 - has fold expressions and some other c++17 features.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod GCC 7 is c++17 complete (not libstdc++  though)

Comment: This isn't valid C++; what exactly is `Is` - a function parameter pack or a template parameter pack or something else? And did you really mean `for i in Is`?

Comment: `return i` I guess you mean `return idx`?

Comment: I clarified the pseudo-code. The expression `Is[i]` is not actual c++, but refers to the i'th parameter pack argument. The `auto... Is` is legal c++17 and is the same as `template<typename... Args> f(Args&&... Is)`.

Comment: @RandomBits I don't think you can put a parameter at the beginning? At least both clang and gcc can't call `index` this way.

Comment: `auto...` outside of lambdas is not legal C++17. And even in the concepts TS it wouldn't be equivalent to your version.

Answer (score 4):

I can't get `auto...` to work, so I changed the signature of `index`.

You will need an auxiliary function (`index_helper` here) to use `index_sequence`, since it relies on template argument deduction to fill in the indices.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename... T, size_t... i>
//                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
//                        use deduction to make {i...} = {0, 1, 2, ..., n}
static int index_helper(const std::array<int, sizeof...(T)>& strides,
                        std::index_sequence<i...>,
                        T... Is) 
{
    return (0 + ... + (strides[i] * Is));
}

template <typename... T>
int index(const std::array<int, sizeof...(T)>& strides, T... Is) {
    return index_helper(strides, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>(), Is...);
//                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                generates {0, 1, 2, ..., n}
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", index({1, 100, 100000, 1000}, 2, 3, 5, 7));
    // 507302
}
```

Comment: Silly not to make it `constexpr` given the types involved. :-]

Answer (score 3):

If you can hammer down the argument pack into one single type that is cheap to copy/move, you can just make it into an array:

```
T arr[] = { static_cast<T>(Is)... }; // for some T, possibly common_type_t<decltype(Is)...>
```

Then you can just turn your pseudocode into real code.

If that's not feasible, a comma fold can be used:

```
int idx = 0, i = 0;
(..., (idx += Is * strides[i++]));
return idx;
```

Comment: I did't realize you could use and modify an index variable in a fold like that. That is useful.