# Parameter Pack and std::array

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++20

I believe this was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849675/c17-efficiently-multiply-parameter-pack-arguments-with-stdarray-elements), but I could be wrong. Is it possible to parameter pack an `std::array`?

```
    template < typename _Ty , typename... _Rest > requires _sqrable_variadic_operation < _Ty , _Rest... >
        auto accumulated_sqr ( _Ty n , _Rest... q ) { return sqrof ( n , q... ); };
```

```
        // Element container of size _Sz and type of _Ty.
        std::array < _Ty , _Sz > m_Elems;
    public:
        . . .
        auto length ( void ){
            return accumulated_sqr ( m_Elems  );
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::array` supports the tuple-like interface which means you can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to extract its elements into an argument list of a callable object:

```
auto length() const
{
    return std::apply([](auto&&... qs) { return accumulated_sqr(decltype(qs)(qs)...); }, m_Elems);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9b38b9b1f047def)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using `std::index_sequence` as a helper:

```
template <std::size_t Sz = 2 , typename Ty = float>
class vector {
protected:
    using Elem_Container_t = std::array<Ty , Sz>;
    Elem_Container_t m_Elems;

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    auto length_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return concepts::accumulated_sqr(m_Elems[Is]...);
    }
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    vector (Ts... elems) : m_Elems {elems... } { }

    auto length()
    {
        return length_impl(std::make_index_sequence<Sz>());
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d0fdd5de50f1532)

---

Note: Names beginning with an underscore followed a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.  You are not allowed to use names like `_Sz` or `_Ty` in your program.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, works flawlessly & I'm confused those are just shortened versions of `_Type` or `_Size`, I've never been told that previously sorry.